# Why does the Apache Camel mail component send the body as an attachment?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel 2.22.0 and have a simple route that is sending an email (with a few property references):

```
public class EmailFailureRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() {
    from("seda:mail")
        .setHeader("To", simple("{{mail.failure.to}}"))
        .setHeader("From", simple("{{mail.failure.from}}"))
        .setHeader("Subject", constant("TEST!"))
        .to("velocity://templates/failure-mail.vm")
        .to("{{mail.smtpServer}}");
  }

}
```

What I expect to get is a normal email with the text from the Velocity template in the body of the message. What I actually get is an email with the text from the Velocity template attached to the email. It looks like this in MS Outlook:

[image: Camel sends mail message body as attachment?]

Why the attachment? How do I get the mail component to insert the result of the Velocity template directly into the email message body?

**UPDATE:**

By turning on the 'debugMode' flag on the mail component, I was able to see the content of the actual email as it's being sent to the SMTP server. It appears that my problem is that the Content-Type is 'application/json'! So now it makes sense that the body is attached but I have no idea why the Content-Type is set this way. Even setting the query parameter 'contentType=text/plain' on the mail end point has no effect on the final Content-Type of the email message.

Comment: Is your mail plain text? Or is it html? Outlook in particular can be stubborn about content. Could you send the mail to a Gmail account and check. I had to jump through hoops to get Outlook displaying images correctly via Apache camel mail component. MS has it own way of handling mail in Outlook.

Comment: The mail component uses MIME type text/plain by default, although I've tried text/plain and text/html with the same result. I also tried sending the email to a GMail account and the email still had an attachment instead of text in the body.

Answer (score 4):

While I still don't really understand what's happening here, I do have a workable solution. The only way I could get the content type of the email message to change was to set the 'Content-Type' header on the Camel message before routing to the mail end point:

```
.setHeader("Content-Type", constant("text/plain"))
```

I couldn't even get the content type to change by using the 'contentType' query parameter on the mail component.

Comment: Yeah like I said there was some hoops to jump through. I had to insert images into the mail(html body) and there was a lot of extra things I had to set. Should have blogged it down somewhere in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

how are you recently and gone through something similar and solved it in the following way I hope it will be helpful

```
@Handler
public void attachmentValidate(@ExchangeProperty("MAIL_ATTACHMENTS") List<Attachment> attachments,
        Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Message in = exchange.getIn();
    if (attachments != null) {
        for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
            FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
            String mimeType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(attachment.getName()
                    .substring(attachment.getName().indexOf('.'), attachment.getName().length()));
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(mimeType)) {
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(attachment.getValue());
            in.addAttachment(attachment.getName(), new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(decoded, mimeType)));
        }
    }
    exchange.setProperty("MAIL_ATTACHMENTS", attachments);
}
```